# The easiest routing in Fat-Free Framework (installed via Composer)

Tags: fat-free-framework

I want to configure the routes for my project via F3. First I installed him via Composer and then I used the instructions about routing engine from [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fAng7nIQKpM&list=PLX0Ak4vUBQfClFDicUaSfm-urMi_kt3cg&index=2) and [This](https://fatfreeframework.com/3.6/routing-engine).

Then in browser if I'm going to URL `localhost/myproject/` it is working fine. But if I'm going to URL `localhost/myproject/route1` it isn't working for me and gives 404 server status error. Why?

My code in "index.php":

```
require_once('vendor/autoload.php');

$f3 = \Base::instance();

$f3->route('GET /', function() {
    echo '123';
});

$f3->route('GET /route1', function() {
    echo '345';
});

$f3->run();
```

It is the easiest project without anything with only F3. Where I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure you got this [.htaccess](https://github.com/bcosca/fatfree/blob/master/.htaccess) in your folder and in case that this does not help, comment in the `RewriteBase /` and adjust the path to match you sub-folder ("myproject").